# Check if a Discord.js DM went through

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I know you can send a DM like this:

```js
message.author.send("Go to example.com for help");
```

But some people have the setting that allows other server members to DM them off:

[image: Screenshot of that option]

How do I find out if the DM actually sent or not? I know this is possible in the Discord API, since other bots do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the user has that option, or isn't DMable, it will throw an error, namely:

```
DiscordAPIError: Cannot send messages to this user
```

Now, we can catch that error and run a command based on it, say replying in the channel that the user can't be DMed.

```js
user.send(...).catch(async err => message.reply("I can't DM this user"));
// In the above, async is useless, but you can actually do what you want with it.
```

To run more than a single line of command, use a promise based catch.

```js
user.send(...).catch(async err => {
  console.log(err);
  message.reply("I can't DM this user");
});
```

Comment: Yes, it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1):

If a user has that option enabled, DMing them will return an error, so you'll be able to use a [`.catch()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/catch) statement:

```js
user.send().catch(() => console.log('Could not DM this user'));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get error notices aswell as information about the error using `.catch()`

In this example I log the error type and description

```js
// then/catch
member.send(...).catch(error => {
   console.error(`${error.name} :\n${error}`)
   message.channel.send('There was an error when trying to DM this member')
});

// async/await
try {
   await member.send(...);
} catch (err) {
   console.error(err);
   message.channel.send('There was an error when trying to DM this user');
}
```